# Recorded mp3 files lost after sd card was removed while laptop was sleeping

Tags: sleep, mp3, sd-card, safely-remove-hardware

1. I took the sd card from the laptop, while it was in sleep mode.
2. Put it (sd card) into Zoom H2n audio recorder.
3. Recorded some stuff using guitar.
4. Took sd card from audio recorder and put it back into the laptop (while it was still sleeping all the time)
5. Turn on the laptop.

After turing on the laptop I didn't find my new recordings (it happened once before, but I did nothing, due to the recorded stuff was irrelevant). All my old recordings was still there. SD card works just fine, no reading errors, simply zero errors regarding sd card. It just does not contain my new recordings, like I have never done them.

I believe something wrong with tables, while the raw data is still on the sd card. Program "RecoverMyFiles" didn't help. How to recover the mp3 file if it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't fiddle with the card, yet, take it out, lock it and then put it back in. Why? You may ask. Because now you will be sure that no changes will be recorded in the SD card. Now what? I suggest you to use some data recovery tool, like R-Studio, which is pretty straight forward on how to access the data that you can't see but it's still there.

Most of the time you can recover, most of your files, only if the data hasn't changed. When something like a soft format happens, new data will overwritte the old data slowly. That's why it's important that you lock it before you try anything on your computer.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: You should never remove a disk or storage device while a computer is asleep. The operating system may not have left the filesystem in a clean state or may make assumptions about it when it restarts. If you absolutely have to do this then at least turn on the machine *before* reinserting the SD card.

---

Chances are that as the laptop was hibernated when you removed the card it had kept a copy the filesystem table for the card in memory. Putting the card back into the laptop and then powering it back up the operating system had no way to know the contents of the card might have changed so it showed you the last thing it knew.

At this point your card might have actually contained the correct file allocation table with your newly added recording. Simply removing the card and reinserting it *might* have shown up the file.

Here's where the problems start.

If you then chose to eject the card the computer may well have flushed its version of the file allocation table out to the card. Result: file gone. Same if you rebooted the laptop with the card inserted.

You might be able to use a tool such as photorec  to find the file, but having no filesystem record of it will make it next to impossible. It's not that your filesystem is corrupt, it's that the allocation table was refreshed with a "known good" version from before you ejected and reinserted it.